# how can i append my string one time in a div jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have append one time but in the div needs more appends but different text (strings)

I tried to do

```
$("#error").one().append("- Er is geen gebruikersnaam ingevuld." + "</br>");
```

only its doing more then once, I cant use a boolean beacause I need more string in the same focusout functions. Is there other way to do this? (I cant use .html instead of .append because you cant show more strings on one div.

whole code

```
$("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(function(){ 
           var lengte = $(this).val().length;
            if(lengte == 0){
                $("#error").show();
                $("#error").append("- Er is geen gebruikersnaam ingevuld." + "</br>");
            }else if(lengte < 5){
                $("#error").show();
                $("#error").append("- Het ingevoerde gebruikersnaam moet 5 of meer tekens bevatten." + "</br>");
            }else{
                $("#error").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve, and include *all* the relevant code. Your question as it currently stands makes no sense at all.

Comment: for what do you need `one()`. In my opinion it makes no sense. ([show doc](http://api.jquery.com/one/)) you could try `$('#error')[0].innerHTML += "- Er is geen gebruikersnaam ingevuld.</br>"`

Comment: Read the information pages on [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) on the jQuery website. Maybe they will help.

Comment: Show the relevant HTML markup, and describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.html()` to empty the DOM

```
$("#gebruikersnaam").focusout(function(){ 
     var lengte = $(this).val().length;
      $("#error").html(''); // Clearing

      if(lengte == 0){
            $("#error").show();
            $("#error").append("- Er is geen gebruikersnaam ingevuld." + "</br>");
      } else if(lengte < 5){
            $("#error").show();
            $("#error").append("- Het ingevoerde gebruikersnaam moet 5 of meer tekens bevatten." + "</br>");
      } else{
            $("#error").hide();
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanx, I was forcing it with the `.remove` but this is much better!